# Missing options when installing Windows 10 using UTM?

Tags: windows, install, virtualization, apple-silicon

I am trying to install Windows 10 on my M1 Mac.  I have installed a UUP dump of Windows 10 for ARM64 and successfully created an ISO file, following the instruction on the UTM website.

[image]

However, the VM creation wizard in Step 2 contains no "Virtualize", "Windows", or "Import VHDX image" things to select or uncheck, and I see nothing on any page to browse for an ISO image.

[image]

So, where are those options? Or are the instructions out of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are running an out of date version of UTM. You can install the latest version [here](https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/releases/tag/v4.2.5).

Once you have opened the app, you will see a screen like this:

[image: main utm page]

Click the "+" button at the left of the top bar and you will see this:

[image: new VM]

Now click "Virtualize".

[image: VM]

Now click "Windows".

[image: ISO selection]

Now select your ISO in the menu shown.

Then go through the rest of the settings (RAM, disk size, etc) and the VM will run.